# Do I have to take the receipt of a laptop I bought in USA when I go to my home country?

Tags: usa, airports, airport-security

Do I have to take the receipt of the laptop I bought in USA with me, when I'm traveling to my country? The laptop is new, not opened.

Comment: Note that you will most certainly have to pay taxes on it when you arrive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take the receipt so that you can prove the amount you paid for it at customs when you return to your country. Otherwise the customs agent may try to estimate the value of the item, and their estimate could be more than you actually paid. This is especially relevant if you paid less than the full retail price of the item.